# Different jar export sizes

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export

I have a question with exporting jar files in Eclipse.

When I export my program as a runnable jar on my desktop it is ~16mb. When I export the same program from my laptop it is less than 1mb. It still runs perfectly when exported from my laptop as well. It is a tiny program and I was shocked when it was 15mb.

Is my desktop putting too many libraries or something in my jar file?
What should I do to only export what my program needs?

Comment: Similar to what @reporter suggests, try this command: `jar tvf <jarfilename>` on both your machines and see what's getting added in the bigger file.

Comment: Your question clearly indicates the need to automate your build, instead of doing it manually. In your case you should be able to use that export wizard to store an ANT file containing the necessary steps. Put that under version control (together with the project) and the builds will be the same again on all machines that you use.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the program set up on both computers, it may be that the build environment is different on each.

Right click on the project in the package explorer, select "Build Path..." -> "Configure Build Path..." and then "Libraries".  Now, compare the libraries between the two computers.

If the project is working on your laptop, correlate the libraries and only select those that are required.

I also want to highly recommend using Maven with the Shade plugin rather then managing your projects through Eclipse.  In this way you will (should?) never have this problem, while still having an executable jar.  Moving between IDEs will also be straightforward.

Comment: I tried deselecting all the libraries on my desktop but the export is still the same size :(  Btw I am VERY unfamiliar with build paths and libraries

Comment: Have you made a file comparinson between the two versions (the 15 mb version and the smaller version) ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your export options. The second dialog provides three radio boxes. Try the second one that called "Package required libraries into generated JAR". The generated jar is smaller than the other generated with the first option.

By the way... you can take a look into a jar file if you using Winzip, Winrar, Totalcommander, etc. The reason is thar the algorythm to generating a jar, war or ear file is similar to zip algorythm.

Comment: It's not just *similar* to ZIP, it *is* ZIP!

Comment: Thanks for responding, but when I package my jar, I get errors and my gui won't load.